# Get two values from one with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div>345000000, 46400000000</div>
```

How do I make two values from the text of this `<div>`? They are divided by comma.

We should get `var value_1 = 345000000` and `var value_2 = 46400000000`

Comment: Another case of over-dependency on libraries... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 <div id="numbers">345000000, 46400000000</div>
 <script>   
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var parts = $("#numbers").html().split(",");
      var value1 = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
      var value2 = parseInt(parts[1], 10);
      alert(value1);
      alert(value2);
    });
 </script>
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Look up Javascript's string.split() function.

Comment: Not _exactly_ the answer, but... :)

Answer (score 2):

Grab the value, split 'em up.

```
<div id="nums">12, 15</div>

var str=document.getElementById("nums").innerHTML;
var nums = str.split(",");
alert(nums[0]); //gets first number
```

Answer (score 1):

**Answer: http://jsfiddle.net/morrison/F38FC/**

**Notes:**

- Shows how to grab multiple divs.
- Uses JavaScript's `String.split()`.
- Open the console to view the pieces.

Comment: you linked to an empty fiddle

Comment: I caught it. My pages are taking a long time to load right now, so it took a while to update it.  Thanks for the concern, though